# How to create a Popup in Windows Phone 8.1 that for which the contents will fit the screen?

Tags: popup, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I want to create a Popup and add the user control to it.

I've created a UserControl and I'm adding it to a Popup as outlined below. It's almost working, but unfortunately it's appearing like this, with text refusing to wrap, even though I've specified `TextWrapping="Wrap"`:

[image]

This is what I'm doing:

User Control:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App3.MyPopupContent"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App3"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Border BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
        <StackPanel Background="White">
            <TextBlock Text="My Popup" TextAlignment="Left" 
                       FontSize="40" 
                       Foreground="Black"/>

            <TextBlock Text="You can position a popup by setting the PlacementTarget, PlacementRectangle, Placement, HorizontalOffset, and VerticalOffsetProperty properties." 
                   FontSize="20"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   Foreground="Black"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </Border>

</UserControl>
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Popup p = new Popup();
        p.Child = new MyPopupContent();
        p.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to make the Popup and its contents stay within the confines of the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to set the Width and Height of the child control of the Popup.

Try opening the Popup in the MainPage's loaded event and set the child's width and height to be the MainPage's ActualWidth and ActualHeight.

Comment: That seems like it would be a logical solution, and it's one of the first things I tried. I should have stated in the question. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @DaveDev What's the problem with it? It works just fine for me. :?

Comment: .... uh oh - it seems you're right and I'm guilty of misreading your answer. I was setting the width of the `Popup` and not `MyPopupContent`. In my defence it's still early and I haven't yet had my coffee.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. You can try this.

```
<UserControl .....
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          Background="#920101">
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

LayoutRoot.Width = App.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
LayoutRoot.Height = App.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
```